# Do Shopify Ajax API Calls count towards limit?

Tags: ajax, api, shopify

Thought I would ask if the Shopify call limits on API use include Ajax API calls as well?

My App has fairly light backend API requirements, but does have some fairly active frontside calls. Doubt I'll brush up against the limit unless a store has a ton of simultaneous visitors, but it would be good for me to know either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Shopify Support Forum](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/ajax-api-call-limit-48658), there is no limit on API calls via the Ajax API:

> There are no limits for Ajax calls per shop per 10 minutes. Ajax requests like HTTP requests experience no bounds in Shopify: your shop can handle any traffic. More traffic means more HTTP requests and also — possibly, if you use Ajax — more Ajax requests. It's all good. Bring it on.

Comment: Thanks. Looked for that but couldn't find an answer. That is good news indeed for my App!